# How to add a close button to jquery Lightbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, lightbox

I recently made a Lightbox and I want to add a close button to it.  Here is what I have:

```
    <style>
        .black_overlay{
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0%;
            left: 0%;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: black;
            z-index:1001;
            -moz-opacity: 0.8;
            opacity:.80;
            filter: alpha(opacity=80);
        }


        .white_content {
        width:600px;
        height:560px;
        padding: 16px;
         top: 5%;
         left: 25%;
         position: absolute;
         display: none;
        -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
        -moz-border-radius: 20px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        border:2px solid #FFFFFF;
        background-color:#FFFFFF;
        -webkit-box-shadow: #C9C9C9 8px 8px 8px;
        -moz-box-shadow: #C9C9C9 8px 8px 8px;
        box-shadow: #C9C9C9 8px 8px 8px;
        z-index:1002;
        overflow: auto;

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">here.................................................................................................</a></p>
        <div id="light" class="white_content"><center><img src="http://theamazingmonth.pusku.com/files/Help.png">
<br>
<!--- Text for Help.</--->
<p align="left">
<div class="tilt pic">
    <img src="http://theamazingmonth.pusku.com/clues/Envelope.png" height="114" width="193" alt="">
  </div>

<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">x</a></div>
        <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I add a close button to the top corner of the popup window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add class `close` on `<a>` tag and put into `<div>` tag, content too.

```
<div id="light" class="white_content">
    <div class="white-header>"
        <a class="close" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">x</a>
    </div>

    <div class="white-body">
    content here
    </div>
</div>
```

On class `.white_content` remove `overflow: auto;`

I have made it, you can see on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fauzi/3zYTs/3/embedded/result/) , [edit jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fauzi/3zYTs/3/)

Answer (score 0):

### How to add a close button to jquery lightbox:

Live example, put this in a file named `test.html`:

```
<html>
    <head>        
        <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.lightbox_me.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>

<style>
  #my_lightbox{
    display: none;
    width: 500px;
    height: 170px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #eef2f7;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 14px 22px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #536376;
  }
</style>

<script>
  var dispatchpopup = function(){  
    $('#my_lightbox').lightbox_me({
      centered: true,
      onLoad: function() {
        $('#my_lightbox_text').html("Stuff");
      }
    });
  }
</script>

<a href="#" onClick="dispatchpopup();">Clicky</a>

<div id="my_lightbox">
  <div id="my_lightbox_text"></div>
  <button id="penguin" onClick="$('#my_lightbox').trigger('close');">CloseME</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**In the same directory as test.html you need to include the files `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` and `jquery.lightbox_me.js` which can be found here:**

http://jquery.com/download/

http://buckwilson.me/lightboxme/

**Screenshot of what happens when you click the link.**

[image]

When you click the close button in the popup the popup closes.  You could hook that close event onto anything.