# What is the best way to make css and html using only css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create lightbox using four images. For some reason, each link opens the first lightbox image.

[image: HTML CSS CODES]

[image: ACTUAL IMAGES]

Comment: All the hyperlink of the four images point to #img1 :)    <a href="#img1">...

Comment: how do I fix it can you help

Comment: On rows 17 - 20 - 23 of your index.html you have to change #img1 with: #img2 on row 17, #img3 on row 20 and #img4 on row 23...

Comment: DO you know how to create close X button top right corner to close the images when open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your links' `href` property is equal  to `#img1`.

You should give your `a` tags the `href` attribute of the `id` of the corresponding lightbox image link:

Thumbnail Image Link 1:

```
<a href="#img1"><img src="image/url"></a>
```

Corresponds to Lighthouse Image Link 1:

```
<a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img1"><img src="image/url"></a>
```

Thumbnail Image Link 2:

```
<a href="#img2"><img src="image/url"></a>
```

Corresponds to Lighthouse Image Link 2:

```
<a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img2"><img src="image/url"></a>
```

Thumbnail Image Link 3:

```
<a href="#img3"><img src="image/url"></a>
```

Corresponds to Lighthouse Image Link 3:

```
<a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img3"><img src="image/url"></a>
```

Thumbnail Image Link 4:

```
<a href="#img4"><img src="image/url"></a>
```

Corresponds to Lighthouse Image Link 4:

```
<a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img4"><img src="image/url"></a>
```

Comment: I have a different issue now, How do I make "X" button to close the image when its open.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627507/how-to-add-a-close-button-to-jquery-lightbox